# My house vs our house when speaking directly one on one

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

If I call a plumber and tell him I need service at an "address". Then he calls back to say he's lost, which of these would be grammatically correct to say?

> My house is second on the right.
>
> Our house is second on the right.

The original conversation was between him and I, no one else involved. The house is owned by my wife and I. If I say *our* its because its not just mine but he only knows of me so is it ok to say *my* house?

Comment: It depends on whether you consider the house to belong to you, or also to your family/other residents.  This choice is sensitive to several factors.

Comment: You ask which is "grammatically correct". I'd prefer a "the" before "second" in each case, but *My* vs *Our* doesn't affect the grammar of the sentence.

Comment: It also depends on the reason for the direction.  If you're in a car, getting a lift to your house, you'd likely say "my house", since other residents are irrelevant.  If instructing someone on how to find your house to attend a party you'd typically say "our house", since presumably the party involves everyone in the house.

Comment: So if my wife is irrelevant in the conversation as to whos house it is then my house is fine to say.

Comment: Just a point, if you were the sole owner would you say "The house is owned by I"? If not why use "I" to describe the joint ownership?

Answer (score 3):

Both of these are perfectly correct. You can use whichever one you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Either is correct - but since the plumber does not know anything about your wife (or any other member of your family) - and since the details regarding ownership are irrelevant...I would probably keep it simple and say "My house".

Answer (score 0):

Strunk & White advocate for minimal communications.

Adding in irrelevant information only clouds the message.

The house is a bit impersonal, but probably more correct.

"It the second house on the right"